# Core Data migration. loadPersistentStores() error

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, migration

I'm trying to migrate my entities but my app crashes on loadPersistentStores() every time. When I install the app the first time everything's alright, so I think this is definitely migration problem. It crashes with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)"

AppDelegate part:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Timetable_3_0 v2")
    let storeURL = URL.storeURL(for: "group.com.kondiko.Timetable", databaseName: "timetable")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in //Error appears here
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Migration Policy

```
class DaysMigrationPolicy : NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
    
    @objc func identificatorFor(id:Int16) -> UUID {
         return UUID()
     }
    
    @objc func isDisplayedWith(id:Int16) -> Bool {
         return true
     }
    
}
```

Migration model[image: 1]